# Логирование Java

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Проблема с логами. В общем не подхватывает моя конфигурация log4j.xml, если я ложу его рядом с JAR.

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", String.valueOf((new File(PATH, LOG_FILE).toURL())))
```

Пишет вот такое:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurat
```

Если упаковываю в JAR, или добавляю его туда "насильно" после компиляции, то все естественно работает.

Версия логов:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

То, что описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579468/how-to-set-log4j-property-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), тоже не помогло. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем вот такое простое решение, после чего пользователь может редактировать конфиг по своему усмотрению ([оригинал статьи](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html)).

```
 LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
 File file = new File(PATH, LOG_FILE);
 context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Единственное что мне пришлось в resource держать файл log4j2.xml, со следующим содержимым

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
</Configuration>
```

что бы избавиться от ошибки, которая все равно так и не исчезла, но при этом все работало

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurat
введите сюда код
```